# corona lua sql update statement correct syntax when using variables

Tags: sql, lua, coronasdk

This may seem very basic but I cannot find correct syntax when using a variable.

This works:

```
local updateTable = [[UPDATE userDetails SET month_id = 100 WHERE id=1]]

db:exec( updateTable)
```

the below doesn't:

```
local myVariable = 100

local updateTable = [[UPDATE userDetails SET month_id = myVariable WHERE id=1]]

db:exec( updateTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the concat operator, `..`, like this:

```
local updateTable = [[UPDATE userDetails SET month_id = ]] .. myVariable .. [[ WHERE id=1]]
```

If `myVariable` comes from outside your app, beware of SQL injection. See: [Lua mysql, need a way to escape data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318525/lua-mysql-need-a-way-to-escape-data), or Google for [lua + "prepared statement"](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lua+prepared+statement)

Comment: @user1462136: If it worked, it's customary to accept his answer by pressing the green checkbox on the right.