# How to insert into mysql database using a variable instead of a string

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-connector

I am trying to use luasql.mysql and execute multiple INSERT statements from a file to a mysql database. I can not seem to figure out how to use a string variable instead of using a string. I want to execute from a for loop, looping though a file of strings. Any help would be appreciated.

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
local env  = mysql.mysql()
local conn = env:connect('mydb','myusername','mypassword','myip')
print(env,conn)
file = io.open("sqldumps.sql")
lines = file:lines()
print("Contents of file:");
for line in lines do  
  status,errorString = conn:execute( '"line"' )
  print(status,errorString )
end
```

Comment: Use `conn:prepare()` to create a prepared statement.

Comment: do you have an example of how its used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318525/lua-mysql-need-a-way-to-escape-data

Comment: Maybe y'all should try reading the actual question instead of just assuming and giving a completely irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually really simple:

```lua
for line in file:lines() do
  status, errorString = conn:execute(line)
  print(status, errorString)
end
```

Lua knows that `line` is a string, so you don't need any quotes around it. In fact, if you add them, Lua will treat it as the actual text "line", not the content of the `line` variable.

---

A hint on `for` loops: `file:lines()` just so happens to return a single function that you can use in your `for` loop, but this isn't always the case.